# JavaScript Max number of checked input type checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Using ASP.NET to generate several checkboxes. Looking for a JavaScript solution that will test any checkbox starting with the name `pdf*` to see if more than 5 are checked, then alert over that number.

There are other checkboxes I do not want this to run on that do not have the name `pdf*`.

Thanks in advance.

here is an example of my checkboxs:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pdf14" value="2250"></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="pdf15" value="2251"></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="pdf16" value="2252"></td>
 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="2253"></td>
```

**<<<NOT A PART OF THE COUNT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var numSelected = 0;
var current;

for (var i=inputs.length;i--;) {
    current = inputs[i];

    if (current.type.toLowerCase() == "checkbox" && current.checked && current.name.indexOf("pdf") == 0) {
        current++;
    };
};

if (current > 5) {
    alert("You've got " + current + " selected! :(");
}
```

If you happened to use jQuery, it'd be as easy as

```
var selectedPdfCheckboxes = $('input:checkbox[name^=pdf]');

if (selectedPdfCheckboxes.length > 5) {
    alert("You've got " + selectedPdfCheckboxes.length + " selected! :(");
}
```

Edit:

The jQuery selector I've used (`^=`) reads as "start with", so no * equivalent is needed.

The jQuery code will execute wherever it is placed, however it must be executed no sooner than `document.ready()`, to ensure the elements you are selecting are present in the DOM. If you place it inside document.ready, it will fire as soon the document ready event is fired. You might want to place the code inside an event handler for another event.. such as the submission of a form?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aForm").bind('submit', function (e) {
        var selectedPdfCheckboxes = $('input:checkbox[name^=pdf]');

        if (selectedPdfCheckboxes.length > 5) {
            alert("You've got " + selectedPdfCheckboxes.length + " selected! :(");

            e.preventDefault();        
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: nice, but even though it is in my page it doesn't seem to fire. i am trying the jQuery solution. should I add pdf*? is the * a wildcard in jQuery?

Comment: I wonder if this works without jQuery:

... var els = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=pdf]][type="checkbox"]:checked');
if ( els && els.length > 5 ) {
    } ...

Comment: @ r. Hill I tried that got: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Tue, 20 Jul 2010 17:59:34 UTC


Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 11
Char: 1
Code: 0

Comment: The original answer should work well, either the plain ol' javascript or the jquery method.  If it's not firing as you say, where are you running it?  If it's just in the global js scope, then it would try to execute before any of your <input> elements were added to the page.  Is your js code in a function that gets called later?  Or in a `$(document).ready(function() { /* code */ } );` block?

Comment: I tried it in the $(document).ready(function() and it fires as soon as the load happens and I get the alert without checking boxes. When I take it out, it never fires no matter how many I check.